# SQL Server 2008: Can I view past user actions?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am fairly new to SQL Server administration and was wondering if there is a way to query the system to track user actions.  The user has appropriate permissions.  I would just like to see what they are doing each day.

I'm wondering two main things:
1) Can I see a history of tables they've only VIEWED?
2) Can I see a history of tables they've MODIFIED (insert, update, delete)?

Many thanks in advance!

-->> S.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the following approach:

1. Launch [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to write logs
2. Enable [Auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280526.aspx)

Comment: That will show all of the above information?  Basically all actions, down to who even opened a table, even if they didnt modify and information?

Comment: Ah, I checked it out more thoroughly.  It seems that this is what I'm looking for.  Thanks.